# Are Applescript dictionaries shareable or available without access to the app?

Tags: applescript

I wish to write (what should be) a fairly simple script for an application on another machine that I don't have on my machine. I do need to know what some of the available command are though. How can I get hold of the dictionary for that app without installing the app on my machine?

Any help or insight will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **AppleScript Dictionary**, an **XML** file with a **.sdef** extension, for a given *app* is typically found within the *application bundle*, e,g. for **iTerm2**:

```
/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/iTerm2.sdef
```

You can copy the **.sdef** file to your computer and open it in **Script Editor**.

That said, you may not be able to *compile* the *script* without the **App** installed, so debugging your *code* may be difficult.

A trick I've used, to just *compile* the *code* but not *test* the *code*, is to create a dummy *application bundle* of the target application. Just make a *folder* of the application's *name* with a **.app** extension.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance of this, I only just got the chance to try it out (something about life and plans comes to mind…). Thanks for the help, it's much appreciated.